# How do I browse the raw data collected by Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm looking for a way to browse the time based database raw data, in a way similar to how SQL Server Management Studio gives you access to the raw data held within the relational database SQL creates. It can be a GUI or console based, because with SQL you can do either or, I'm really hoping for some kind of graphical interface though. Is there a way to browse through the data?

Or can someone simply explain how the raw data would look, if there were such a way? With SSMS, I'm able to get so much information about the tables, fields and rows, and see how it's all structured and related.

I do understand that it's kind of apples and oranges when talking about the differences between a Time Based DB and a Relational DB, but surely there's a way to browse through the database itself? Or is it just using PromQL?

The Web UI doesn't seem to provide anything like this, where I can see a way to browse through the ingested data.

Comment: I have troubles imagining what you want to do, and how you expect it to work.

Comment: Browsing through Prometheus' data is done with promQL. PromQL cannot give you access to meta information of the data, if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: Structure in which data is stored is were rigid, and you can find it in source code of Prometheus, if you want to investigate or study something.

Comment: @markalex I'm coming from a SQL background, so I'm trying to wrap my head around how another DB is fundamentally set up. 

I guess now that I think about this more, I am hoping for some kind of tool that would be a GUI equivalent to SQL Server Management Studio, that allows someone to actually look through all the raw tables, and visually see what's stored where. 

I'm learning more about PromQL and I know that SSMS uses SQL Queries to generate the tables seen in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus provides an ability to query data with [PromQL](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) via [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) and [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) HTTP APIs.

If you need querying raw samples for some [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series) matching the given [series selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) on a specified time range `(t-d ... t]`, then the following query to `/api/v1/query` HTTP API can be issued:

```
curl 'http://prometheus-host:9090/api/v1/query?query=some_series_selector[d]&time=t`
```

For example, [http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/api/v1/query?query=up[5m]](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/api/v1/query?query=up%5B5m%5D)

See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is not RDBMS, and does not provide similar openness of it's enternal structure. You as a user are not supposed to know how data is stored internally. Data structure used is rigid, and does not intend any user intervention/tinkering/optimization.

If you really want to know how data is stored, Prometheus has a [open source code](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus), so you are free to investigate it to find all the details you want, but I don't see any benefit in that: considering the fact that Prometheus only stores scraped metric, I don't think there is much to investigate there.

Regarding querying data I don't see any benefit to knowing how data is stored, since you are still expected to use promQL, that doesn't allow any kind of query modifications with hints, plan optimizations and such.

Although you might try using Grafana's Explore feature: it has autosuggestion for metric names, labels and other syntax sugar of that nature. This might ease your learning curve a bit.